# Correct division of applications into modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

This is how my project looks like. I have 3 modules
https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services

```
common
```

module common - contains all general DTO objects and exceptions

```
core (compile common)
```

module core - s the core of the application. It has entities, database access services and other services such as sending an email

```
web (compile core)
```

module web - the main startup module. It contains all controllers, configurations, classes responsible for security

I would like to ask your opinion about this modularisation of the project. Is this a good division?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate common module further into `common-dto` and keep entities as part of `core` module. That way, `common-dto` can be shared as a dependency with other microservices to talk to your microservice via, for example, feign clients. Also, you can have a parent `core-backend` module, which can have `core` and `engine` modules. That way, if you ever need to serve html static content using your spring boot app, you can easily add a ui module without having to rename existing modules.